# Google chrome 22.0.1229.94 m and GWT plugin

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, plugins

I just tried to run GWT plugin with Chrome 22.0.1229.94 m but it failed... Says something like

> "Cannot load GWT DMP plugin"

:(
Anyway, Chrome proposes to install [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gwt-developer-plugin/jpjpnpmbddbjkfaccnmhnkdgjideieim) GWT plugin but when I press "to install" installation doesn't start at all :S

- Google Chrome: 22.0.1229.94 m
- GWT: 2.3
- GWT Developer Plugin 1.0.11338
- OS: Windows XP Pro SP3

So my question is...
Why may GWT plugin for Google Chrome fail and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was apparently a bug in the Windows build of the plugin. Should be fixed now: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/4fWzySzpbtQ/BqwEV_FxxUoJ

You might also try to uninstall the extension and then re-install it (but wait for the new version to come).

Comment: Yes you right, according to group talks, it is some kind of DLL bug for win... Just now I re-installed the plugin update from chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gwt-developer-plugin/… and it worked :)